# Drop unpushed commit after pull

Tags: git

I committed some changes to my git repo but I did not push. Rather, the push failed because there is a file in this commit too large for the repository. I would like to get rid of this commit. The problem is that since my failed push I've done a pull.

How do I resolve this? I cannot make heads nor tails of the git man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably looking for `git reset --hard`

If you are on branch `master` and your repo is named `origin` command `git reset --hard origin/master` will remove all commits and changes which are not in `origin` repository.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to keep your local changes and only remove the commit, do `git reset --soft`